# Polymorphic association with has_one, can't create through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, has-one

I've got a polymorphic association with a has_one and it gives me an error when trying to create through association.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :userable, polymorphic: true
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :gender, :description, :dob
  has_one :user, :as => :userable
end
```

If I try to do:

```
s = Student.new
s.user.create
```

I get and error Undefined method create for 'nil'

But! If i change the association to has_many users then I can now preform the same lines above.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that user is nil since you haven't assigned a value to it.
You should use something like:

```
s.build_user(...)
```

or

```
s.create_user(...)
```

Comment: Perfect! what i don't understand is the when I use has_many, the users array is also nil but it still allows to create..

Comment: @UriKlar Great! When you use has_many, the association is initialized to an empty array and that's why you are able to call methods on it since it's not nil. With the 'has_one' the association can't be initialized automatically, you have to call one of the helper methods (build_xxx, create_xxx) or assign it explicitly like x.foo = Foo.new